# Length of circular list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

From 'A gentle introduction to lisp':

> If given a circular list such as #1=(A B C . #1#) as input, LENGTH may
>   not return a value at all. In most implementations it will go into an
>   infinite loop.

Is this still true? Was/is it a bug? Why not check the nature of the list first?

Comment: Sylwester's answer touches on "Why not check the nature of the list first?" very well — it's expensive.  Dan's answer points you to `list-length` which will check the nature of the list (but not necessarily *first* — it may be easier to do it while computing the length of the list).  Modern implementations do still have this behavior;  it's written into the spec, and SBCL, for instance, hangs if you pass a circular list to `length`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In modern implementations like R7RS Scheme and Common Lisp they do identify circular list, but to reduce overhead CL has both `length` that might hang and [`list-length`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_list_l.htm#list-length) that returns nil if a circle is detected.

There is no simple way to see the nature of a list when all you see is one cons at a time. What you do is iterate each step in one variable and every two steps in the second staring at the second element. If those two ever is the same object there is a circle reference. That is called [the turtle and hare algorithm](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Comment: +1 all around:  good description of the difference, and good reference to turtle and hare.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Implementation dependent features are really bad apples to pick.

Comment: I think that most implementations will still hang.  The big problem is that there's no guarantee about whether you get an error, or just the implementation hanging, or what.  It's always important to remember that CL was an attempt to unify a bunch of Lisps, so sometimes there's just enough specification to make everyone's existing implementation be within bounds.  Sometimes that means underspecifying.

Comment: CLISP will hang if you just create a circular list in REPL (without tuning of printer). I think it creates a circular list and then tries to show result, which takes long time to be shown ;-) `(setf *print-circle* t)` can help here.

Comment: @Mark That's a completely different problem. You can have a circular list and do stuff with it without ever printing it out. The Algorithm to identify circular structures like `*print-circle*` turns on is very much more complex and uses a lot more memory because the `car` too can point to a previous `cons`.

Comment: @Sylwester, well it's quite obvious that this sort of printing requires lots of checking. But sometimes you just want to test something in the REPL.

Answer (score 4):

[`length`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_length.htm) is meant to work on sequences in general; the circularity issue is relevant for lists but not for, say, strings or arrays.  [`list-length`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_l.htm) is specialized on lists and works as expected for proper lists, but returns `nil` for circular lists.